# XML in VB having issue with child nodes included in for loop

Tags: xml, vb.net, system.xml

I am trying to pull xml data out in a specific order. I need to know why in the section marked with the ***** that this loop is pulling data from the descendant nodes. i only need nodes  from that node 'level'. If anyone can help thanks allot.

The post is making me add more text but i have nothing more to say about it.

```
 Public Sub importPies(piesxml As String, outputcsv As String, version1 As String, pwat As frmDetailProgress)


        Dim xmlDoc As XElement
        Dim xmlNodes, currentNode As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
        Dim textout As String = ""
        Dim x, xl As Long
        Dim RootElements() As String
        Dim nsname As String
        Dim fileroot As String
        Dim primaryElement(0) As String


        Dim fileStreams() As PiesFileStream
        Dim dataline(0) As PIESDataLine
        fileroot = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outputcsv)
        xmlDoc = XElement.Load(piesxml)
        nsname = "{" & xmlDoc.Elements().ElementAt(1).Name.Namespace.ToString & "}"
        pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.add("Setting up for PIES " & version1 & " Conversion to csv"))
        fileStreams = CreatePIESCsvHeader(outputcsv, version1, False)

        ' get root elements

        RootElements = GetPiesRootElements(version1)
        For x = 1 To RootElements.Length - 1
            xmlNodes = From nm In xmlDoc.Elements(nsname & RootElements(x))
            ReDim Preserve primaryElement(primaryElement.Length)
            For xl = 0 To xmlNodes.Count - 1

                If xmlNodes.Elements(xmlNodes.Elements.ElementAt(xl).Name.ToString).Count > 1 Then
                    primaryElement(primaryElement.Length - 1) = xmlNodes.Elements.ElementAt(xl).Name.LocalName.ToString
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next xl



        Next x
        pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.add("Starting Conversion to csv .", "G"))
        For x = 1 To RootElements.Length - 1
            pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.add("Decoding " & RootElements(x)))

            currentNode = From nm In xmlDoc.Elements(nsname & RootElements(x)) Where nm.Name.LocalName = RootElements(x)

            ' check to see if any nodes exist based from current pies def
            If currentNode.Count > 0 Then

                ' check to see if first node has multiples, if so we will dig into it otherwise we will build from here

                If currentNode(0).DescendantNodes.Count = 1 Then

                    For Each node In currentNode
                        ReDim Preserve dataline(dataline.Length)
                        dataline(dataline.Length - 1) = New PIESDataLine
                        dataline(dataline.Length - 1).FieldName = node.Name.LocalName
                        dataline(dataline.Length - 1).Data = node.Value
                    Next
                    WritePiesData(dataline, fileStreams, RootElements(x))
                    pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.add("Single record Decode Method", "G"))
                Else
                    pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.add("Multiple record Decode method data lines =" & currentNode.LongCount.ToString, "R"))

                    ' ***** problem is here descendent nodes are included 

                    For Each node As XElement In currentNode

                        ReDim dataline(0)

                        decodeNode(node, dataline)
                        WritePiesData(dataline, fileStreams, RootElements(x))

                    Next
                End If

            Else

                pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.add("** No Data **", "R"))
            End If

        Next

currentNode.descendantnodes

        CloseFileStreams(fileStreams)
        pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.add("Done !"))
        pwat.Invoke(Sub() pwat.EndAndClose())







    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see what it's doing?  Does `currentNode` have the contents that you expect?  If it does, I expect that the problem is in `decodeNode` which you haven't shown.

Comment: I guess it would help if you post the relevant parts of the XML also. Also: with `For Each node As XElement In currentNode` you're iterating through the child nodes of `currentNode`, but it sounds like you're only interested in ´currentNode´ itself. BTW, I'd personally use the `.selectNode/.selectNodes` method of `XMLDocument` to limit the nodes to those which are needed. Saves you from iterating through unnecessary data.

Comment: That is it i am stepping through child nodes and i don't want to do that there.